# FTPClient constructor fails with latest SDK tools and ADT

Tags: java, android

I have code which worked fine with previose version of SDK tools and ADT (v16). But after I updated both to v19 apache commons FTPClient constructor call cause program to crash without even throwing any exception!
Following line of code causes crash whenever I put it in my code:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
```

I've tried to solve the issue by taking latest commons.net library (v3.1) but it did not help. I'm using SDK 2.2 (API 8). Any thoughts?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: are you sure it is not throwing any exceptions?

Comment: I wrapped it by try catch (Exception) and set breakpoint inside catch - it did not reach it

Comment: Might be some problem with library referencing in new tools
When running in debug mode first error message in LogCat is:
E/dalvikvm(6212): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient', referenced from method ***.***.***.***.<init>

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was in new way of libs referencing introduced in ADT 17. Here is the link with solution that helped me: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17